Updating appengine-web.xml to app.yaml file
I have a GAE application in Java 21 and updated the app.yaml file from the appengine-web.xml file. I am using web.xml for the servlets, and all related files like cron.xml, datastore-indexing.xml, logging.properties, queue.xml, and web.xml are placed in the WEB-INF folder, and the pom.xml and the app.yaml files are in the root directory. Here is the app.yaml file.
runtime: java21
instance_class: F2

env: flex

automatic_scaling:
  min_pending_latency: 6s
  max_pending_latency: 8s
  max_idle_instances: 1
  max_concurrent_requests: 50

env_variables:
  JAVA_UTIL_LOGGING_CONFIG_FILE: "WEB-INF/logging.properties"

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored


error_handlers:
  - error_code: 500
    static_file: error500.html
  - error_code: default
    static_file: error500.html


app_engine_apis: true

I have added the following plugin in the pom.xml file
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <projectId>my-local-project</projectId>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

I have consulted chat GPT which said that we need to add the projectId as the above I have added it because I don't have any cloud projectID currently.
Now when I try to run the application locally, it gives me this error
NoSuchFileException during local run
Error occurred during local run. Please first confirm that there is a properly placed appengine-web.xml file.  If missing, either use the Cloud Code shortcut action under:  'Tools > Cloud Code > Add App Engine Support > Google App Engine Standard'
I have also gotten to know that the appEngine-web.xml is expected to run from a standard environment, and the app.yaml file is expecting a flexible environment. I am using IntelliJ Ultimate. I go to the tools-> Google cloud code -> App Engine -> Add app engine support -> and from here select the Google App Engine Flexible, and this error occurs "Cannot add Google App Engine Flexible framework support.".

Where did you see that app.yaml file is only for flexible environment? In which env do you want to run your code - standard, flexible?

in the standard environment.

Provide the link to where you saw this. As far as I know, app.yaml is for both flexible and standard environments
